# Merge 2D Array by key

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, I want to join those like I said below. Merge those arrays by its key.

```
$arr1 = array(
     [0]=>array(
             [a]=>2,
             [b]=>3,
             [c]=>4
          );
      );

    $arr2 = array(
         [0]=>array(
                 [d]=>5,
                 [e]=>6,
                 [f]=>7
              );
```

Now I want an array like

```
    $new_arr = array(
              [0]=>array(
                     [a]=>2,
                     [b]=>3,
                     [c]=>4,
                     [d]=>5,
                     [e]=>6,
                     [f]=>,
                 );
           );
);
```

Please help me

Comment: Merge arrays? [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `array_merge` along with `foreach` as

```
$arr1 = array(array(
             'a'=>2,
             'b'=>3,
             'c'=>4
          )
      );

$arr2 = array(array(
                 'd'=>5,
                 'e'=>6,
                 'f'=>7
              ));
$result = array();              
              foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
                $result[] = array_merge($value,$arr2[$key]);
              }

print_r($result);
```

Or 
if having single array as

```
$result = array_merge($arr1[0],$arr2[0]);
```

Or using `array_replace_recursive`

```
$result = array_replace_recursive($arr1,$arr2);
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/377582)

Comment: You'll have to remove the value for key 7 to match OPs requested output

Comment: I think its a mistake done by OP while posting an output @scrowler

Answer (score 3):

In this case you may use `array_replace_recursive`, if keys are different it will works as array merge saving pathes

```
$new_arr = array_replace_recursive($arr1, $arr2);
```

result

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["a"]=>
    int(2)
    ["b"]=>
    int(3)
    ["c"]=>
    int(4)
    ["d"]=>
    int(5)
    ["e"]=>
    int(6)
    ["f"]=>
    int(7)
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't have knowledge about that function +1.

Answer (score 1):

Which is used to merge the array,

```
$new_arr[0] = array_merge($arr1[0],$arr2[0]);
```

know more about [array merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)